# Adding a TRIGGER to phpMyAdmin MySQL table to DELETE a row in Table A it's corresponding row is deleted in Table B

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables called `RESERVATIONS` and `RESERVATION DETAILS`.

The primary key `reservationId` for `RESERVATIONS` is a foreign key in `RESERVATION DETAILS`.

In my website, the user can delete a reservation from the `RESERVATION` table.

How can I add a TRIGGER so that, if the `reservationId` is deleted from the  `RESERVATION` table, the row corresponding to the `reservationId` in `RESERVATION DETAILS` is also deleted?

Using phpMyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to unconditionally delete `RESERVATION_DETAILS` when you delete the parent row in `RESERVATIONS`, you can define `ON DELETE CASCADE` on your foreign key. Your definition for `RESERVATION_DETAILS` will look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE RESERVATION_DETAILS (
    reservationDetailId INT,
    reservationId INT,
    -- etc...

    FOREIGN KEY (reservationId)
        REFERENCES RESERVATIONS(reservationId)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#idm139661572120064) for further details.

Comment: This is probably the better way between our two answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple trigger to delete from another table on delete:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_reservation_id AFTER DELETE on RESERVATIONS
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM RESERVATION_DETAILS
        WHERE RESERVATION_DETAILS.reservationId = RESERVATIONS.reservationId;
    END
```

Change your table names accordingly.

If you need to delete this trigger ever, this is the syntax:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS delete_reservation_id ;
```

Comment: Thanks but it still isn't working. I have double checked and the table/row names match up.
Here:
CREATE TRIGGER reservation_detail_delete AFTER DELETE on reservation
  `FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM reservationdetail
        WHERE reservationdetail.ReservationID = reservation.ID;
    END`

Comment: @user3081458 - `ON RESERVATION`, or `ON RESERVATIONS`?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie the table is called `RESERVATION` so it's `ON RESERVATION`

Comment: @user3081458 - no worries. It's just that you called it `RESERVATIONS` in your question.